# How to save data to multidimensional array in plist file

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, plist

I would like to save some configuration data to my plist file which contains arrays and regular variable types. It looks like this:

(http://s10.postimg.org/f2xpgur1l/plist.png)
(sorry I can not attach any image)

My function which do this looks like so:

```
// Saves the data into a plist file
func saveObject(i_fileName: String, i_keyForValueToSave: String, i_valueToSave: String, i_keyForXInitializer:String, i_valueXInitializer: String) {

    var fileName: String = i_fileName

    var keyForValueToSave: String = i_keyForValueToSave
    var valueToSave: AnyObject = i_valueToSave

    var keyForXInitializer: String = i_keyForXInitializer
    var valueXInitializer: String = i_valueXInitializer

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    var dict: NSMutableDictionary = [keyForXInitializer: valueXInitializer]

    //saving values
    dict.setObject(valueToSave, forKey: keyForValueToSave)

    //writing to plist
    dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)

    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    println("Saved Data.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
saveObject("Selection.plist", "Item 0", "testConfig, "Item 3", "XInitializerItem_01")
```

The result looks then like so:

(http://s13.postimg.org/kbq103707/result.png)
(sorry I can not attach any image)

As you can see, the "testConfig" which should be saved into an array will be saved as a normal string in the pilst file. Which is not the goal for me. Every item I would like to add to this array. Im really new in SWIFT and Im a but stuck in space. Any help would be great! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below creates the plist you need, you just need to populate the values correctly to match your needs

```
func saveObject(i_fileName: String, i_keyForValueToSave: String, i_valueToSave: String, i_keyForXInitializer:String, i_valueXInitializer: String) {

    var fileName: String = i_fileName
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    var dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    var item0 = [1,2,3]
    var item1 = [1,2,3,4]
    var item2 = false
    var item3 = "xInitializerItem_01"
    dict.setObject([item0, item1, item2, item3], forKey: "selection_01")
    item0 = [4,5,6]
    item1 = [5,6,7,8]
    item2 = true
    item3 = "xInitializerItem_02"
    dict.setObject([item0, item1, item2, item3], forKey: "selection_02")
    dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

    let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    println("Saved Data.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description)")
}
```

That is may result from the code above:

[image]

You cannot append values to the plist, so everytime you save it you need to save all values again

Comment: It works perfectly thank you for that! I can also store data into the plist. But is it really like so, that the plist is dont stored in xcode, its stored somwhere deep in my sytem. Developer/CoreSimator/Devices... And so on. The data is filled there but when I want to read it, its taking the data from xcode which is of course not populated...

Comment: Yes just enter the values you want to enter in the variables item0..item3 and it will be save. This file is not save in the application, plist files create in  xcode cannot be changed ,only read, once the application is installed, the file is saved in your document folders so your application can change it when need.

Comment: OK thank you for the clarificatiin. Just the last question. When I would like to save a second or third array (eg. selecio _02, or selection_03) into the same file, how would you do that? Every try I've done till now endet up in overwriting the existing array... Thx a lot for the time!

Comment: in the line "dict.setObject([item0, item1, item2, item3], forKey: "selection_01")" change the string selection_01 for  selection _02, or selection_03. that will create new keys for you

Comment: Hmm I've tried it now exactly you wrote and I face the same issue again. Its overwriting me the previous saved selection with the actual one. In the worst case I will make 3 files for selection1, 2 and 3...

Comment: Can you add the code you are using now in the end of your post so I can try to see what is happening?

Comment: Sure I can do! I've just updated the initialpost, after the **edit:/** sign.

Comment: Its a bit trick as you cannot append values to a plist, you need to add the new values with the old values and save the whole lot, I update the answer I hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You declare `valueToSave` as an `AnyObject` but it holds `i_valueToSave` which is declared as a `String` in your function parameter.

So when you do `dict.setObject(valueToSave, forKey: keyForValueToSave)` it saves a `String`.

You should declare the type of your `i_valueToSave` function parameter as `AnyObject` instead of `String`, then inside the function you will be able to cast `i_valueToSave` to the desired type before saving it.

Let's say `i_valueToSave` is an array of strings, then:

```
if let valueToSave = i_valueToSave as? [String] {
    dict.setObject(valueToSave, forKey: keyForValueToSave)
}
```

If it's an NSArray:

```
if let valueToSave = i_valueToSave as? NSArray {
    dict.setObject(valueToSave, forKey: keyForValueToSave)
}
```

Etc.